# Central div for content with graphical background image that reaches from far container edge to left edge of screen?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a content div that is centred on the page:

```
<div id="container>
</div>

#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px
}
```

I want a background image that is a 1px high and 1000px wide gradient to span from the right edge of #container to the left edge of the web browser. I've made the gradient so the edge colour is a solid colour so I can hopefully just specify a solid colour as background so if the browser goes super wide it doesn't look janky.

any ideas how to do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you correctly, the solution requires you to matte the gradient background image and center it horizontally within the appropriate element (be it `#container` or its immediate parent element).  Investigation of `padding` values for `#container` might also yield some good results.

Comment: the issue is that i want the container content to remain centre :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/WZbFQ/).

And to stretch the left colour over the total height of the window, replace `absolute` with `fixed`.

But it is much easier to make the background image say 3000 pixels wide (and only the center 960 pixels containing the gradient, [like this one](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/gradient3000x1.png/)) and attach it to the background as follows:

```
body {
    background: url('/images/gradient3000x1.png') repeat-y center;
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about the height of your content.